# How to use code repositories in Eclipse?

Tags: java, svn, version-control, mercurial, repository

How can I use code repositories in Eclipse?  Should I use SVN or Mercurial?  What way is easiest to use with Eclipse on a Mac.  I tried to use Google Code (with SVN and Mercurial), but I need to get JavaHL for it to work.  Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use code repositories in Eclipse?

It depends on the version control technology, but Eclipse has support for a number of technologies, via the "Team" user interfaces.

> Should I use SVN or Mercurial?

Your choice.  There are other version control technologies supported too; e.g. Git and CVS.  Search in the Eclipse Marketplace.

You really need to do your own research on this, and figure out which one best matches your and your project's requirements.  (SO is not a survey or recommendation site, so don't expect people to give you recommendations ...)

> What way is easiest to use with Eclipse on a Mac.

Erm ... see above.

> I tried to use Google Code (with SVN and Mercurial), but I need to get JavaHL for it to work. Is there an easier way?

Unfortunately, the SVN plugins for Eclipse require an implementation of the native JavaHL drivers:

- For windows, the drivers are included when you install from the update service.
- For other platforms, they are not.  You can download them for free from Collabnet (after a signup song-and-dance).  The installation and setup is non-trivial, but the process is well documented, and it works if you complete all of the steps as per the documentation.  This is, IMO, a "poor user experience", but nobody seems to care enough to fix it.  (Guys ... the word you are looking for is "compromise".)

The JavaHL libraries are only required by the SVN plugins.  Other version control technologies don't require this.

Comment: “Unfortunately, the SVN plugins for Eclipse require an implementation of the native JavaHL drivers” — this is untrue, when you reboot after you installed Subversive you can select SVNKit which is a pure Java implementation of SVN.

Comment: @LaurensHolst - OK.  I just don't recall that option being available.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using subclipse for a while, and I think it is great enough for small projects.

You can try EGit if you are using git as your repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for "Eclipse version control", you'll get many recommendations.

- SVN (need to install the JavaHL library)
- EGit (recommeded if you are using Git)
- SourceAnywhere Standalone (provided by the company I'm working for)
- Mercurial (MercurialEclipse)

You can test out the above tools to see which meets your requirements best.